# Mule ESB - How to use WS Consumer Response as input for WS Consumer 2 - Error coercing number to string

Tags: mule-studio, mule-component

I am struggling to use the output from WS Consumer A as input for WS Consumer B using a transformer component.

The error I am getting is "Cannot coerce null to string".

The IDNumber from WS Consumer A output is of type number which I am trying to convert to a string as input of WS Consumer B

```
    %dw 1.0
%output application/xml
%namespace ns0 http://www.iLov2kodez.com/fakeNamespace0
%namespace ns1 http://www.iLov2kodez.com/fakeNamespace1
%namespace ns2 http://www.iLov2kodez.com/fakeNamespace2

---
{
    ns0#SearchCustomerDetails: {
        ns0#IDnumber: payload.ns0#Response.ns0#Result.ns1#IDnumber as :string
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Cannot coerce a :null to a :string
Type                  : com.mulesoft.weave.mule.exception.WeaveExecutionException
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
```

Answer (score 1):

are you sure your getting response from WSConsumer1. You can try thing using mule break point or using logger. Try to post your piece of xml code to better understand the issue.